# Find MIN/MAX date in a range if it matches criteria of other columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

> Column A is date
>
> Column B is criteria

I want to find the `MIN` date for each criteria. I tried using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> with

```
=MIN(MATCH(B2,B:B,0))
```

but thats not quite right because I need to refer to Column `A` somehow to get the date. I'm pretty confident this can be done with arrays, so any help would be great.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel: Find min/max values in a column among those matched from another column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20904092/excel-find-min-max-values-in-a-column-among-those-matched-from-another-column)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this (array formula):

```
=MIN(IF(B2=B:B,A:A))
```

Comment: I ended up using vlookup, but I will try this next time I have to run this data report, probably this week.

Comment: For anyone reading this, note that it can take 30 to 60 minutes to calculate this on a spreadsheet with 50K rows. Obviously a database would be a more efficient, long term solution.

Comment: Hmm, you are right. The formula approach is too slow with that volume of data. This would be very easy to do with a pivot table. Well worth a few extra minutes to learn the process.

Comment: I want to do it in small range... but I am getting an error #value!

Comment: @ShravyaBoggarapu make sure you are committing the formula as an array by pressing ctrl+shift+enter (not just enter).

Comment: Yea, thank you.. I had pressed Ctrl+shift+enter but I may have not done it right cause when I re-tried a few times, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

An even more compact array formula is:

```
=MINIF(B2=B:B,A:A)
```

**NOTE 1:** Complete using `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` to enter the formula as an [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7).

**NOTE 2:** The two-formula method (i.e., using `=MIN(IF(B2=B:B,A:A))`) is more flexible and works in more cases than the single-formula method shown here but I've included it as an answer as a possible option.

Answer (score 1):

```
=SMALL(INDEX(($F$2:$F$14=F3)*$D$2:$D$14,),SUM(COUNTA(F:F)-COUNTIF(F:F,F3)))
```

If your criteria is repeated and want to find the min date for that you can use this without shift+ctrl + enter function.

- date is `D` column
- criteria is `F` column