# Max Value in a Hlook up

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

I have a huge table in this format below that makes VLOOK up etc not possible.
I would like to get from every month the highest value from the small sample like below.

```
2-2018  2-2018  2-2018  3-2018  3-2018  3-2018  3-2018  3-2018  3-2018  
   7      7       8       7       8       9       7       7      9
```

On an other slide I can the create a sheet were I then need to find back the month and correlate it to the table were it then find the highest value for that month:

```
   A     B
2-2018 = 8
3-2018 = 9
```

I want to know the MAX per month and have been working with MAX, INDEX and MATCH, but cannot get it to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional Min and Max in Excel 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570223/conditional-min-and-max-in-excel-2010)

Answer (score 1):

Try using a MAXIFS formula. For example, if the horizontal dates and numbers are in cells A1:Z2 and the vertical date your looking for the max of is in A4: formula in B4

```
=MAXIFS(A2:Z2,A1:Z1,A4)
```

Edit for versions less that 2016

You could also do a sumproduct for formula using arrays. Note: this is a volatile formula and could slow down the workbook is used in excess.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX((A1:Z1=A4)*(A2:Z2)))
```

Comment: `MAXIFS` function was introduced in Excel 2016, so good answer, however may not work for some people :)

Comment: Ok ok. Went with a more dangerous approach

Comment: Don’t forget to mark as the answer if this worked for you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a dynamic and deep analysis for your data you can use **Power Pivot** it is a free add-in for Excel 2010+ that you can download and activate easily. You can connect directly your data and use the query editor. There you will have a lot of tools to edit your data.

For your specific request follow these steps:

[image]