# Find nearest positive and negative value to 0 within a table of values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
     A            B       C        D      E                F                   G    
1                 Q1     Q2       Q3      Q4    Nearest negative value to 0   -10 
2   Asset 1      -50     85      -90      70    Nearest positive value to 0     5    
3   Asset 2      -28    -80      -45      60          
4   Asset 3      -30     50       55     -10                              
5   Asset 4      -20      5      -80     -15
6   Asset 5       35    -30       27     -98
7
```

In `Cells A1:E6` I have different assets with their performance from quarter `Q1-Q4`. 
 The performance can be positive or negative.

In cell `G1` and `G2` I want to find the nearest negatvie and positive value to `0` in `Cells B2:E6`. 
 In this case this would `-10` and `5`. Therefore, I tried to go with the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570223/conditional-min-and-max-in-excel-2010):

```
G1 = {MAX(IF($B$2:$E$6<0,1,0)*($B$2:$E$6))}
G2 = {MIN(IF($B$2:$E$6>0,1,0)*($B$2:$E$6))}
```

However, both formulas give me `0` as a result.

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

---

**NOTE:** All values in `Cells B2:E6` are unique.

Comment: Edit the 0 inside the `IF` formula to 99999 should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the `*`:

```
=MAX(IF($B$2:$E$6<0,$B$2:$E$6))
```

And

```
=MIN(IF($B$2:$E$6>0,$B$2:$E$6))
```

These are Array formula and need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

---

Along with the AGGREGATE given by Forward Ed if on has Office 365 Excel:

```
=MAXIFS($B$2:$E$6,$B$2:$E$6,"<"0)
```

And

```
=MINIFS($B$2:$E$6,$B$2:$E$6,">"0)
```

Comment: Thanks again Scott.

Comment: I like the `MINIFS MAXIFS` options as they are non-array calculation formulas

Answer (score 3):

For largest negative number

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,B2:E6/(B2:E6>0),1)
```

For smallest positive number

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,B2:E6/(B2:E6<0),1)
```